# File recovery that keeps folder structure?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

I somehow wiped the partition on my external 3tb hard drive. I've been using filescav to try and recovery the files. I have had some luck getting back the files, but they are coming back as Unknown.

I need a recovery tool that will keep the folder structure. Although i can't help but feel all that has happened is that the hard drive has forgotten who he was. I know none of the data is corrupted.

Running Windows 7 64-Bit, i have the hard drive plugged in via sata now.

In disc management it displays 2tb as raw and the other tb as unallocated

Comment: Well, did you try `testdisk` for restoring the partition + data? Also, working on the real data might destroy it, you'll want to make a copy of the harddisk with `dd` or something similar.

Comment: i'm not writing anything to it, been trying to recover for a while now. But nothing writing to it, or formating.

Comment: running testdisk now. looks promising. I always trust command line a lot more :p.